# Can you wield a double weapon in one hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, double-weapons

Part of the wording under double weapons is confusing:

> A creature wielding a double weapon in one hand can't use it as a
>   double weapon—only one end of the weapon can be used in any given
>   round.

The reason this is confusing is all double weapons are two-handed

> Two-Handed: "*Two hands are required*" to use a two-handed melee weapon
>   effectively. Apply 1-1/2 times the character's Strength bonus to
>   damage rolls for melee attacks with such a weapon.

So are double weapons capable of violating the two handed rule? If so shouldn't double weapons qualify as one-handed weapons? or is it possible to wield all two-handed weapons in one hand with some form of penalty? If applicable please use examples in your answers.

Answer (score 5):

This dates from 3.5e (or earlier?) - the quote below is from the [d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#doubleWeapons), and is the same in the PF SRD.

> **Double Weapons**
>
> Dire flails, dwarven urgroshes, gnome hooked hammers, orc double axes, quarterstaffs, and two-bladed swords are double weapons. A character can fight with both ends of a double weapon as if fighting with two weapons, but he or she incurs all the normal attack penalties associated with two-weapon combat, just as though the character were wielding a one-handed weapon and a light weapon.
>
> The character can also choose to use a double weapon two handed, attacking with only one end of it. **A creature wielding a double weapon in one hand can’t use it as a double weapon—only one end of the weapon can be used in any given round.**

This is open to interpretation, but my opinion is that, as double weapons are already a special case that differ from the general rules for two-handed weapons, that WotC intended for them to be wieldable one-handed as this *implies*, as well as the *explicitly* stated two-handed or two-weapon methods.

**However...**

It appears that Paizo took a different view. There is [a feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quarterstaff-master-combat) to specifically allow a character to wield a quarterstaff (a double weapon) one handed.

> **Quarterstaff Master** (Combat)
>
> You can wield a quarterstaff as either a two-handed or one-handed weapon.
>
> Prerequisites: Weapon Focus (quarterstaff ), base attack bonus +5.
>
> Benefit: By employing a number of different stances and techniques, you can wield a quarterstaff as a one-handed weapon. At the start of your turn, you decide whether or not you are going to wield the quarterstaff as a one-handed or two-handed weapon. **When you wield it as a one-handed weapon, your other hand is free, and you cannot use the staff as a double weapon.** You can take the feat Weapon Specialization in the quarterstaff even if you have no levels in fighter.

While [the value of the feat is argued](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=7418.msg219528#msg219528) (due to the "WotC" interpretation of the double weapon rules), Paizo's [official position](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m8r8?Quarterstaff-Master-Am-I-missing-something#24) is that you can't wield one handed without it.

> Hey there folks,
>
> You cannot normally use a double weapon in one hand unless it is sized smaller than you. This feat allows you to get around that restriction.
>
> Jason Bulmahn
> Lead Designer
> Paizo Publishing

Comment: And that is a statement I can support; a tougher +1 than most, I imagine, but you have it. This is a good and thorough answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first quote *implies* that double weapons are all hand-and-a-half weapons, à la the bastard sword, and can be used as one-handed weapons. It does not, however, outright state this, and that is confusing. It does *not* state that you can ignore the “Two hands are required” clause for two-handed weapons, and double weapons are definitely<sup>1</sup> two-handed weapons.

Strictly speaking, the first quote is insufficient to allow you to do this. It does not state that you *can* wield the double weapon with one hand, it just says that *if you do*, you can only use one end. It is extremely unlikely that they would intentionally print a rule that would never see use, however; more likely, it was intended that double weapons be allowed to switch between being two-handed, one-handed, and one-handed-plus-light at will, with all that each of those states implies. But this is not stated, so as likely as it seems, we cannot say for sure.

1. <sup>Kinda sorta. The rules define double weapons as two-handed weapons, with a special exception that allows you to use double weapons for TWF, in which case your *TWF attack penalties* are determined as if the ends were separate weapons, one-handed and light respectively. However, almost all tables treat double weapons used to TWF as one-handed and light for *all purposes*, not just for the TWF attack penalties, and this does seem more consistent with how double weapons are treated and referred to in the rest of the rules.</sup>

Comment: Does a weapon's double weapon quality trump the weapon's effort when using a double weapon designed for a creature 1 size category smaller than the weapon's wielder? That is, can a Medium orc use one-handed as a double weapon a halfling's quarterstaff?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I wouldn’t think so; that would even be a case where the *when you do this thing you usually couldn’t* would actually come into play under even strict RAW.

Comment: Bulmahn's note that Adeptus cites mentions inappropriately sized weapons specifically so I thought it might be a thing.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sure, a smaller double weapon can be used as a one-handed weapon, but when you do that, you can’t use both ends. That seems consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Having done some research, **you cannot use a two-handed weapon with one hand, even if it's a double weapon**. [This question](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qut) on the Pathfinder FAQ states definitively that you can't use a two-handed weapon in one hand, effectively or not.

However, **the rules for double weapons apply to exceptions that allow you to use a two-handed weapon with one hand**. For example, the [Titan Mauler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/titan-mauler) Barbarian Archetype can use two-handed weapons with one hand by taking a -2 penalty, but if they were to use a double weapon with one hand, they could only use one end of the weapon at a time. This also means that using a double weapon smaller than your current size category (such as a Small Dire Flail used by a medium creature), you could only use one end at a time.

Answer (score -2):

I've always understood that a double weapon used with two hands are actually two weapons, like when your character uses a sword and a dagger or a couple of scimitars.

When you use the weapon with a single hand means that the usage is restricted, so you must count it as a single weapon and also you can apply only part of the character strength.

Comment: Joshi your mostly inaccurate. As clearly stated all double weapons are two handed weapons. They can be wielded as though they are two different weapons. However after a number of things being searched a double weapon can only be wielded in one hand under special circumstances, such as if it's a smaller size, class abilities that allow you to wield a two handed weapon in one hand, or feats like quarter staff master that specifically allows you to wield the quarter staff with one hand

Comment: In any case there is no rule that forbids the usage, you just have to apply the right bonus/penality to it. 
To me that's clear by the rules and this does not mess with my writing (even when other answers are better than mine).